# Is there any way to encapsulate bash functions?

Tags: bash, shell, environment-variables, bash-scripting

I'm writing a simple script `script.bash` that is supposed to export some variables environment, to use it in my current session I have to source it

```
$ . script.bash
```

**script.bash**

```
function fun1() {
    # TODO
}

function fun2() {
    # TODO
}

function main_script() {
    # ...
    # ...
    fun1 # calling fun1
    # ...
    func2 $ 1 $2 # calling fun2
    # ...
}
```

to use `script.bash`, call `main_script` function.

**Question**:

- Is there any way to hide `fun1` and `fun2`,  and prevent them from being called outside from `script.bash`.

Comment: Asking about security is a massive question (one that is pretty much unanswerable with the current info provided), perhaps you could share what specific concerns you may have with security?  Things that'll help in a general sense are the ownership/permissions of the script and what it/the owner/group are allowed to do on your system.

Comment: @nerdwaller The second question has deleted.

Comment: I not a bash programmer, but if you want to limit the accessibility of the functions, and they're not used elsewhere, perhaps encapsulate their definitions inside the main function?

Answer (score 2):

Add `unset -f fun1 fun2` at the end of the script.
The `-f` spesifies function, as `unset` can unset both functions and variables.

[unset man page](http://ss64.com/bash/unset.html) entry

Comment: then, how can I use  the functions in my main function ?

Comment: Unless I'm missing something: You run the script, the main function runs when you call it, it does what it does; after everything is done with the functions, the last line which unsets is run. Unless you exit the `return` or `break` the script in one of the functions, the unset will unset them

Comment: the script is sourced in .bash_profile , so  all the functions are **unseted** before even calling the main function.

Comment: since you are doing it that way, you could add the unset to the bashrc

Comment: It seems impossible to achieve what I want.

Answer (score 1):

Script:

```
unset my_protected_function
function my_protected_function() {
    echo "function executed"
}
[ "$0" != "/bin/bash" ] && unset my_protected_function
my_protected_function
```

When you run it directly, look ma no function

```
$ ./test.sh
./test.sh: line 15: my_protected_function: command not found
```

When you source it:

```
$ source ./test.sh 
function executed
```

That what you had in mind?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve what you want by making the body of `main_script()` use parentheses (creating a subshell) instead of using curly braces.  For example, your script.bash can be rewritten like this:

```
function main_script() (
    function fun1() {
        # TODO
    }

    function fun2() {
        # TODO
    }

    # ...
    # ...
    fun1 # calling fun1
    # ...
    func2 $ 1 $2 # calling fun2
    # ...
)
```

This prevents fun1() and fun2() by being callable outside of main_script(), but still allows main_script() to be callable.  Note, however, you will no longer be able to set global variables from within main_script.  The subshell and its context will dissapear when the function finishes executing.

Answer (score 0):

you can mangle the function name, then use 'alias'/'unalias' to bind/unbind it to a human-readable name when you want to use it.